# DAX Measure not Filtering Results as it should be (when sliced by another attribute)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset of employees working on month-to-month basis,

The dataset looks something like this,

| Date | Emp Code | Project Code | Allocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/1/2022 0:00 | 1 | A | 0 |
| 8/1/2022 0:00 | 1 | A | 0 |
| 9/1/2022 0:00 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 10/1/2022 0:00 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 11/1/2022 0:00 | 1 | A | 0.2 |
| 12/1/2022 0:00 | 1 | A | 0 |
| 7/1/2022 0:00 | 2 | B | 1 |
| 8/1/2022 0:00 | 2 | B | 1 |
| 9/1/2022 0:00 | 2 | B | 1 |
| 10/1/2022 0:00 | 2 | B | 1 |
| 11/1/2022 0:00 | 2 | B | 0.2 |
| 12/1/2022 0:00 | 2 | B | 1 |

[image]

I have a **Slicer for Date Range** from which the user can select any date range and data will be filtered accordingly.

I have a **Matrix Visual** that shows allocation of employees **month-wise**. There is an additional **Filter** is applied on this Matrix visual, that it only shows those employees which have been **allocated (have allocation > 0) on all months being filtered**. For example, If I am filtering from August to December, then only the records which have allocation greater than 0 FOR ALL THE MONTHS (August to December) will be shown. I have also attached two examples below to demonstrate this,

[image]

(As only the employee with Emp ID = 2 was allocated on all the months from July to December, so his record is shown only)

[image]

(As both the employees with Emp ID 1 and Emp ID 2 are allocated in ALL THE MONTHS from September to December (filtered range of date), so their records are shown.

This is the measure that I am using currently in this Matrix Visual to filter out the employees which don't have allocation > 0 for all the months being filtered,

```
Employee Allocated All Months Boolean = 
Var _count = 
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[Month]), 
            FILTER(
                ALLSELECTED(Competency),
                Competency[Emp Code] = MAX(Competency[Emp Code])
            )
        )
    Var _total = 
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[Month]), 
            ALLSELECTED(Competency)
        )
RETURN 
    IF(_count = _total, 1)
```

My problem comes in when I **filter the data table**, i.e., when I **filter the Project**. So, right now, Emp ID is working in Project B and Emp ID 2 is working on **Project A**. When I filter the Report by Project A, my dataset will now contain records of only Emp ID = 1.

And now, it starts giving incorrect results. That is, when I am slicing by the Date (July to December), it should show me **Blank** (that is, no records) because no Emp matches the Condition that I am applying. However, it instead shows me Emp ID 1 and only shows the "three months" in which it was allocated (neglecting the other months altogether). That is what I do not want it to do.

[image]

I have tried to fix this in all the ways I could, but still couldn't do it. I tried to use "ALL" with the table in the Calculate but it didn't work for me, I don't know why.

Can anyone help in resolving this issue? Thanks a lot in advance.

**If you would like to use the Power BI File, then you can download it from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X31vAnPlS7gnkHEfcveYpg_wQwE1sKLh/view?usp=sharing**

Comment: you have 3 values for (July to December) for emp1 - sep =1;okt=1;nov=0.2. Why the matrix should be blank?

Comment: @Mik because the values for July and December are 0, so according to my requirement, if any of the months (in selected range) have a 0 value, then the matrix should not show that record. So, for this record, since two of the five values are blank, then the matrix shouldn't show this record.